# Keep event listener on last element of list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an un-ordered list with mutiple li elements inside of it. The last element has an on click event listener which adds another li element to the list, seen in this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/45vyLdra/

What I want to do is have the on click event always be on the last element of the list, even after I have appended the new li. Is there a clean way to do this? If I re-run line 2 of

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("li").last().on("click",function(){
        $("ul").append("<li><a href='#'>Button</a></li>")
    })
})
```

and just unbind the original event it would work but that seems easier said than done.

Comment: If the last `li` always is the same, just move the `li` to the bottom upon each click without creating new ones.

Comment: Don't know how you append new lis. You should post this... But you may have to "redefine" the handler while doing this append. Because on `load`, the event is attached to one defined element. If this element is not the last afterward... JS doesn't know.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The code that appends the `li`s is right in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that you can't attach an event-handler to an element that doesn't yet exist in the DOM on page load.

As such, you need to hoist the scope, and attach the event handler to an element that's not dynamically generated, **[delegating](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** the functionality by passing the target element as a parameter of `on()`.

In this case, you can attach it to the `<ul>`. You can find the last element with the CSS `:last` pseudo-selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul").on("click", "li:last", function() {
    $("ul").append("<li><a href='#'>Button</a></li>")
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Holy! Thank you so much! This was driving me insane.

Comment: *"The problem you have is that you can't attach an event-handler to an element that doesn't exist in the DOM on page load."* That is completely untrue.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: So you know how to attach event to some "future" elements? Tell more, I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

If the last element could be always the same you might use `prepend` instead of `append`. Check it out:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('li').last().on('click', function () {
    $('ul').prepend('<li><a href="#">Button</a></li>')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
</ul>
```

You might avoid **jQuery** at all and use **Vainilla JavaScript** instead:

```js
document.querySelector('li:last-child').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = '<li><a href="#">Button</a></li>';

  document.querySelector('ul').prepend(template.content);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note: In this example I'm using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (an [ES6](http://es6-features.org/) feature)

Answer (score 0):

Add the listener to the ul and check if it's the last child that was clicked before adding the new item.

```js
var growingList = document.getElementById('the-list');

growingList.addEventListener('click', addToList, false);

function addToList(event)
{
  event = event || window.event;
  
  var theList = document.getElementById('the-list');
  var listItems = theList.children;
  var lastItem = listItems.length - 1;
  
  if (event.target === listItems[lastItem]) {
    var htmlToAdd = '<li>' + (lastItem + 2) + '</li>';
    theList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlToAdd);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="the-list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: This also works really well! Thank you for your answer